# How can I expose my Hasura microservice on multiple ports?

Tags: kubernetes, hasura

My microservice has multiple containers, each of which needs access to a different port. How do I expose this service on multiple ports using the Hasura CLI and project configuration files?

Edit: Adding the microservice's `k8s.yaml` (as requested by @iamnat)
Let's say I have two containers, `containerA` and `containerB`, that I want to expose over HTTP on ports `6379` and `8000` respectively.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: www
      hasuraService: custom
    name: www
    namespace: '{{ cluster.metadata.namespaces.user }}'
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: www
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: containerA
          image: imageA
          ports:
          - containerPort: 6379
        - name: containerB
          image: imageB
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: www
      hasuraService: custom
    name: www
    namespace: '{{ cluster.metadata.namespaces.user }}'
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 6379
      name: containerA
      protocol: HTTP
      targetPort: 6379

    - port: 8000
      name: containerB
      protocol: HTTP
      targetPort: 8000

    selector:
      app: www
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Comment: Can you paste your current k8s.yaml along with information what are the other ports you'd like to expose?

Comment: @iamnat: Modified question with `k8s.yaml`

Comment: It looks like you're already exposing multiple ports? Or when you say `expose` do you mean you want these to be publicly accessible from outside the cluster?

Comment: @timothyclifford: yes. Modified the `k8s.yaml` to use a generic example of 2 containers that need to be exposed over HTTP at different ports.

Comment: You have your two containers with port mapping included, what's the actual problem you are seeing? Do you get errors etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
- Add an API gateway route for each HTTP endpoint you want to expose [[docs]](https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/hasuractl/hasura_conf_generate-route.html)

---

Inside the kubernetes cluster, give your k8s spec this is what your setup will look like:

```
http://www.default:8000  -> containerA
http://www.default:6379  -> containerB
```

So you need to create a route for each of those HTTP paths in `conf/routes.yaml`.

```
www-a:
  /:
    upstreamService:
      name: www
      namespace: {{ cluster.metadata.namespaces.user }}
    upstreamServicePath: /
    upstreamServicePort: 8000
    corsPolicy: allow_all
www-b:
  /:
    upstreamService:
      name: www
      namespace: {{ cluster.metadata.namespaces.user }}
    upstreamServicePath: /
    upstreamServicePort: 6379
    corsPolicy: allow_all
```

This means that, you'll get the following:

```
https://www-a.domain.com -> containerA
https://www-a.domain.com -> containerB
```